# Would pulling a wagon cause the creature to be encumbered?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, encumbrance

I am playing a large zen archer monk. I was able to create the character using the race builder. In our last session something came up which made us question having me pull our wagon and if doing so causes me to be encumbered. Now part of it depends on how much weight is in the wagon, but just pulling the wagon itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, there's a weird disjoint between the [carrying capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity) rules and the vehicle rules.  The carrying capacity rules state that whatever your STR is determines your carrying capacity.  For Large creatures, it's x2 that. And then you can drag x5 that. So if you have a 20 STR, for example, you could pull (133 lbs x 2 x 5) as a light load and a max of (400 lbs x 2 x 5) (2 tons!) as a heavy load. (You could argue that wheels on the cart count as a "favorable condition" and could double that, meaning Large STR 20 could pull 4 tons, ideally briefly). But what those dragging/lifting rules don't say is that it's an exception to the normal encumbrance categories, so if you are dragging more than your light/med/heavy load you're encumbered at that level, meaning that in general if you're pulling something like a wagon you'll almost always be heavily encumbered. **So yes, you're encumbered when pulling a wagon.** But there are multiple levels of encumbrance in Pathfinder, which applies? Read on!

The vehicle rules just say "how much of an creature you need to pull it" - so the [light wagon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/vehicles/land-vehicles/wagon-light) requires "1 Large" creature to pull it.  It specifies no weight for itself per se, however, so it's hard to establish if this is a light, medium, or heavy load.

From the [mounts and vehicles movement table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#Table-Mounts-and-Vehicles), however, we can make some inferences. Horse and pony speeds are all around 4 mph, but the fixed cart speed is 2 mph. That's half speed, definitely some level of encumbrance - but none of the encumbrance levels actually halve movement rates. So, not super helpful except to establish that it's surely not for free.

In the end, there is not a smooth continuity between these three parts of the rules so you'll have to rule in a way that's generally consistent with them.  If you're looking for realism, creatures can't pull their max for long, in real-horse-world horses can pull about 1/10 of their body weight over an 8 hour day of travel (only about 175 lbs), but the "equivalent" dead weight (draft) of a cart or wagon tends to be small in proportion to its real weight - a modern carriage (like you might see the tourists riding downtown in a large city) weights 1000 lbs dead weight but its draft is suitable for a single horse to pull around for a shift. For short pulls, the world record for a dead drag is 17000 lbs (just for 7 feet), which means that 4-ton number that seemed big up above isn't all that inconceivable.

Taking that and putting it together with the rules that exist, I'd come up with a flat encumbrance for the muscle driven vehicles (cart and wagons) that makes sense and can be used additively with loads to create character-sensible encumbrance loads.  Even the Large wagon that has a 4000 lb weight allowance can be drawn by 1 Large creature (seems like a terrible rule - none of the listed wagons is so large it requires multiple horses? but whatever), so heavy wagon + 4000 lbs is probably at the limit of ability of a heavy horse (STR 20) while a cart (+300 lbs) should be able to be drawn by a Medium STR 13 pony. So let's say STR 13 can drag up to 750 lbs, if 300 is cargo, then let's call the cart 100 lbs of encumbrance.  It's a medium load empty and a heavy load with 300 lbs of cargo and a driver (and if that driver is fatter than 250 lbs, he's going to have to drop some cargo). Using the same methodology, the ruling I'd use for the load weights of these vehicles (not their true weight, their draft weight) would be:

- Cart - 100 lbs
- Light Wagon, Carriage - 300 lbs (just inside Medium
  empty for a light horse)
- Medium Wagon - 500 lbs (just inside Medium
  empty for a heavy horse)
- Heavy Wagon - 700 lbs (Heavy for a heavy
  horse, and you really need more)

This assumes the wheels are making for "favorable conditions," which should only really happen on roads, I'd remove that favorable condition when going in rough terrain.

Comment: That is a great detailed answer, thank you for it